# Why is my touchpad pointer twitching?

Tags: touchpad

The pointer of my laptop is doing the same twitching that has been expressed by those using a mouse.

Sometimes I lose the pointer altogether. What is the fix for this phenomena?

Comment: Update the driver from the official website. If it is up to date, see if the issue continues in safe mode. If so, it's likely to be hardware, regardless, this it too broad. Take it to an IT shop and see if they can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole host of reasons why this can be the case.

- hardware fault (faulty connection internally can mean that the trackpad can end up feeling biased. Split liquid into electronics can also result in strangeness like this... Faulty connection in USB port?)
- it could be that the driver is misconfigured (wrong protocol can lead to this erratic behaviour under Linux. Guessing it's the same under operating systems as well (though unlikely especially in the case of Windows))
- software screw up (think about changing the sensitivity of the mouse and then all of a sudden it picks up all extraneous, small movement and you endi up with you have end up with)
- it could virus/trojan (I've seen funny stuff including one that placed smiley faces all other your desktop and some others which screwed around with your mouse pointer like this)